# I want to convert a list of strings to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary, mysql-python, pymysql

I stored a twitter data to a mysql db as a json. When I fetch it back, it returns a list of string instead of a list of dictionary. I am looking for a way turn it to a list of dictionaries. This is the format i get the stored data back. "tweetdata" is the column name in the db

```
[{"tweetdata":"[{\"text\":\"b  problem\",\"len\":10,\"Date\":1583160242000,\"Source\":\"Twitter for 
Android\",\"Likes\":0,\"RTs\":0},}]"}]
```

I want it to return something like this as a list of dicts with the column name stripped off

```
[{\"text\":\"b  problem\",\"len\":10,\"Date\":1583160242000,\"Source\":\"Twitter for 
Android\",\"Likes\":0,\"RTs\":0},}]
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid JSON.

Comment: What have you got and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, looks like you provided a wrong json format. Provided that you have a correct json format then you can use json loads function to load the the json data and convert it to dictionary type. Here is code snippet in python.

```py
import json
json_data = '[{"tweetdata":[{\"text\":\"b  problem\",\"len\":10,\"Date\":1583160242000,\"Source\":\"Twitter for Android\",\"Likes\":0,\"RTs\":0}]}]'
parsed_json = json.loads(json_data)
parsed_dict = parsed_json[0]['tweetdata'][0]
print(type(parsed_dict))
for item in parsed_dict.items():
    print(item)
```

Above code snippet will print these.

```
<class 'dict'>
('text', 'b  problem')
('len', 10)
('Date', 1583160242000)
('Source', 'Twitter for Android')
('Likes', 0)
('RTs', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

if your data in `tweetdata` variable then `tweetdata[0]["tweetdata"]`
it'll return like this:

```
[{\"text\":\"b  problem\",\"len\":10,\"Date\":1583160242000,\"Source\":\"Twitter for Android\",\"Likes\":0,\"RTs\":0},}]
```

actually you can do like this:

```
data = [{"tweetdata":"[{\"text\":\"b  problem\",\"len\":10,\"Date\":1583160242000,\"Source\":\"Twitter for Android\",\"Likes\":0,\"RTs\":0},}]"}][0]["tweetdata"]
```

and print `data` you'll get the same result.